# how can i use variable of without functions (javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

how can i use  variable of without functions:

sample:

```
var name = 'Jim';

function is_name()
{
alert(name);
}


is_name() //alert : Jim
```

tanX

Comment: That code works. What's your question?

Comment: Your example works, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Why would some one waste a negative vote on a question like this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is kinda confusing, do you mean this:

```
alert("Jim");
```

or this:

```
var name = 'jim';
alert(name);
```

or this:

```
function is_name()
{
 return 'jim';
}

alert(is_name());
```

or this:

```
function is_name(name)
{
 alert(name);
}

is_name('jim');
```

Or any combination of the above.

Comment: The list could go on for a while...

Comment: i want this : function is_name(name)
{
 alert(name);
}

is_name('jim');

Comment: Right, you want the name to be passed as an argument to the function. If you are serious about learning any programming language, you should buy a good book about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand your question, but is the answer possibly as simple as this (i.e. you don't want to call a function for some reason):

```
var name = 'Jim';
alert(name);
```

Comment: No ... i want using in function

Comment: @erfan - you're going to have to describe it a bit better than that please.

Comment: @erfan: You wrote *"how can i use variable of **without** functions"*. It is really not at all clear what you want.